# StreamPlot ignores some options

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot some vector fields using StreamPlot, but I am unable to get the desired plot as some options are ignored when I add them.

Here is the vector field I am trying to plot:

```
\[Alpha] = Pi/4*(x + y);
Q = {{Cos[\[Alpha]], -Sin[\[Alpha]]}, {Sin[\[Alpha]], Cos[\[Alpha]]}};
```

And here is the plot:

```
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];
StreamPlot[Q . {{1}, {0}}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
 StreamPoints -> Coarse,
 StreamMarkers -> "Segment", 
 StreamStyle -> Thickness[0.003], 
 StreamColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[0.35] &), 
 RegionFillingStyle -> LightGray, 
 RegionBoundaryStyle -> GrayLevel[0.35]]
```

The code above produces the following result:[image: Result]

As we can see, the options `StreamMarkers` and `Thickness` are ignored, as the plot looks the same, if the are omitted. Any idea how to change arrows to lines and set their thickness?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problems come from wrong syntax:

```
Q . {{1}, {0}}
```

This results in a matrix, not a vector. In MMA there is no distinction between row and column vector. Instead, the rule is:

***Summation is done over the last index of the left object and the first index of the right object.***

Therefor you need to write:

```
Q . {1, 0}

StreamPlot[Q . {1, 0}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
 StreamPoints -> Coarse, StreamMarkers -> "Segment", 
 StreamStyle -> Thickness[0.003], 
 StreamColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[0.35] &), 
 RegionFillingStyle -> LightGray, 
 RegionBoundaryStyle -> GrayLevel[0.35]]
```

[image]